Blazor export property of a component to another one
Ive been trying to use foolgpt aswell as other online guides on how to cascade ( or manage some sort of state manager ) in order to control the property of one component from another.
Basically I have the mainlayout which is the father UI of the program.
This is part of it:
    <div class="sidebar" hidden="@(!state.isAutenticate)" >
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    <main>

        <div class="top-row px-4" style="text-align:center;display:inherit !important; ">
            <h1><b></b></h1>
      <table>
                    <tr>
                        @if (state.UserObj != null )
                        {
                        <td>Hello: </td>

                            <td> @(state.UserObj.FirstName  + " " +  state.UserObj.LastName) </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
 </table>
            </div>

            <button hidden="@isMenuBtnHidden" > test </button>



There I have a buttons, which I want to be hidden. that's why I set the value of isMenuBtnHidden to false.
I have the nav menu ( as you can see, it is used here too  in the second line )
and there I simply have a many with links such as:
<div class="nav-item px-3"<NavLink class="nav-linkhref="sklk_read_inp_av">testNav</NavLink></div>

I want to add a method to that Navlink that will toggle the visibility of the button found in the Mainlayout.
So , lets say, whenever a Navmenu click is made, and it refers be to a page ( using href), I want at the same time to display a button that will redirect me back to the Navmenu page ( /home ).
Ive been trying for a long time to do that but it seems Im lacking the knowledge or the unbderstanding of what Im doing wrong.
Any solutions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks and have a nice day.

Do you mean you want to have a "back" button like what the Browsers already have?

Same functionality, but it's within the browser. I want my program to have a button that will navigate between pages. And for example one page has the cretiria to display it while others don't.

If I read this correctly, you want a button to navigate you back to the page you came from.  Say a you clicked a edit button on a list, you want a way back to the list from the edit form.  Correct?  If so, do you want to preserve the state of the page you cam from i.e. in my example you want to return to the correct page in the list?

thats right, but its not to the page I came from basically, lets say I have a navigation menu, whenever one of the options is clicked, I want to have a " back to menu " button, and within the navigation menu lets say I have a submenu, so when clicked I want to display " back to back menu " AND "back to submenu" buttons.  @MrCakaShaunCurtis

I'm afraid you've lost me.  Isn't the menu displayed in the page you've navigated to?

If you want to display a button which can redirect you back to "/home", you could try following :
In App.razor, make sure you used global interactive rendermode  (either server or WASM). Or the "Maninlayout" cannot have interactive.
...
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
...
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

In Navmenu.razor, add "@onclick" to the Navlink tag("counter") with a method to invoke eventcallback change.
...
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter" @onclick="change">
                <span class="bi bi-plus-square-fill-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLin>
...
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> flagChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool flag { get; set; } = true;

    private void change(){
        flagChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }
}

In MainLayout.razor , use "@bind-flag" in  to bind flag with isMenuBtnHidden.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
...
        <NavMenu @bind-flag="isMenuBtnHidden"/>
...
        <button hidden="@isMenuBtnHidden" @onclick="Back">Back to Home </button>
...
@code{
    public bool isMenuBtnHidden { get; set; } = true;

    private void Back(){
        isMenuBtnHidden = true;
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}

Then when you click the "counter" link, this button will show which can navigate to "/".
